# How do remove 'credit card (save)' Payment method from Magento?

Tags: magento

I’m using paypal payment product. If you see the attached file i get 3 options. The first 2 work fine and are actually all i require. The last option

Credit Card (save) doesn’t seem to work. Can someone explain what this option is, also how can i remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Credit Card saved method will allow you to accept credit card information for a purchase, but Magento will make no attempt to verify its accuracy other than a simple luhn checksum.  The credit card information will be stored in the database, encrypted using a call to

```
Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($data)
```

In a default 1.4.2 instal, you can view the payment information (including the credit card) with the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order_payment
```

You can view this Payment method in

```
System -> Config -> Payment Methods -> Saved CC
```

You can also set it's "enabled" config value to "No", which will remove this as an option.

Fully securing credit card information is a Hard Thing™, both from a technical and bureaucratic standpoint. Unless you and your team have the expertise to do it (which, based on your question, I'm going to assume is a no) you don't want this option turned on.

Comment: does not work:
* no POST/GET
* no javascript errors
* and of course no errors in logs
:-(

Answer (score 7):

Just disable it under the payment methods configuration in back-end

Answer (score 5):

It is a really bad option. It saves all the user's credit card information to your database (so that you could process it manually later if you have a hardware terminal but no payment gateway). Head to the admin payment options and disable it and it should disappear.

Answer (score -3):

You should hide it with css `display: none;`

```
.payment-icons-box {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid this way, the method would still be accessible. Disabling in the admin configuration would make it go away and inaccessible

Comment: @MichaelStevens it was my understanding that he wanted to hide paypal banner. I'm sorry.